# getting value from two spinner into string variables

Tags: android, string, spinner

I'm trying to pass the strings "año" and "artista" from two spinners to the next activity and I get the value "año" but "artista" is always void. I used this method to get the values in other activity and there it works but here, "artista" is always void. Moreover, I have tried with switch method and without success.

I hope someone helps me and tells me what I'm doing wrong. I read and look for information before ask for help,

This is my code,

```
public class Buscar extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    String año;
    String artista;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buscar);
        Buscar();

        Spinner spinnerBuscarAño = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.añoSpinner);
        String[] añoBuscar = {"1995", "2000", "2005"};
        spinnerBuscarAño.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, añoBuscar));
        spinnerBuscarAño.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner spinnerBuscarArtista = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.artistaSpinner);
        String[] artistaBuscar = {"Michael Jackson", "U2", "Depeche Mode"};
        spinnerBuscarArtista.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, artistaBuscar));
        spinnerBuscarArtista.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    /*

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int pos, long id) {
        switch (parent.getId()) {
            case R.id.añoSpinner:
                año = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                break;
            case R.id.artistaSpinner:
                artista = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    */

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                               long id){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
        if(spinner.getId() == R.id.añoSpinner)
        {
            año = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }
        else if(spinner.getId() == R.id.artistaSpinner)
        {
            artista = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void Buscar() {

        Button buttonBuscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buscar);

        buttonBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),artista, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Intent intentBuscar = new Intent(Buscar.this, ListadoMusica.class);
                intentBuscar.putExtra("myaño", año);
                intentBuscar.putExtra("myartista", artista);
                startActivity(intentBuscar);


            }
        });

    }

}
```

If someone can help me,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you checked if the value is there in `Buscar()` to narrow down if the problem is in this Activity or the receiving Activity?

Comment: I want to pick the values of the two spinners in this activity and send to another activity. I don't understand why this code is not working here when I can pick values of two spinners with this code in another activity,

Comment: Have you checked if the value is there in `Buscar()` with a log or breakpoint to narrow down if the problem is in this Activity or the receiving Activity?

Comment: Ok, sorry but I didn't understand your first post, I will try and comment, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are trying to catch a string of intent with another name.

Try this code:

**SpinnerTest.java**

```
public class SpinnerTest extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


    String year;
    String artist;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinner_activity);

        Spinner spinnerYear = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        final String[] years = {"1995", "2000", "2005"};
        spinnerYear.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, years));
        spinnerYear.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner spinnerArtists = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        final String[] artists = {"Michael Jackson", "U2", "Depeche Mode"};
        spinnerArtists.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, artists));
        spinnerArtists.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Button btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent searchIntent = new Intent(SpinnerTest.this, SearchActivity.class);
                searchIntent.putExtra("year", year);
                searchIntent.putExtra("artist", artist);
                startActivity(searchIntent);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        switch (adapterView.getId()){
            case R.id.spinner1:
                year = adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Toast.makeText(SpinnerTest.this, year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.spinner2:
                artist = adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Toast.makeText(SpinnerTest.this, artist, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

**SearchActivity.java:**

```
public class SearchActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String year;
    String artist;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive_spinner_value);
        TextView txtYear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtYear);
        TextView txtArtist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtArtist);

        if(getIntent().hasExtra("year")){
            year = getIntent().getStringExtra("year");
            txtYear.setText(year);
        }
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("artist")){
            artist = getIntent().getStringExtra("artist");
            txtArtist.setText(artist);
        }
    }


}
```

It works for me

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for your answer but it isn't working for me, the strange think is I can get the value of two spinners in other activity but in this one it doesn't work. Again "Artist" is void and the toast is void too,

Comment: It is what I don't understand, the code works also for me in other activity but not here